# Memory not cleared in 2 consecutive full GC cycles

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, java-7

Not able to understand what garbage collector is doing here , I can see 3 full GC cycles only first Cycle has cleared some memory ,other 2 cycles memory is not cleared still it has taken 16 secs in each cycle.

```
1189.994: [GC1189.994: [ParNew: 446787K->22515K(471872K), 0.1136668 secs] 1408852K->990343K(4141888K), 0.1144236 secs] [Times: user=0.87 sys=0.01, real=0.11 secs] 
1204.825: [Full GC1204.826: [CMS: 967828K->695710K(3670016K), 20.8721088 secs] 1192388K->695710K(4141888K), [CMS Perm : 133862K->133237K(524288K)], 20.8732268 secs] [Times: user=20.81 sys=0.13, real=20.87 secs] 
1225.703: [Full GC1225.703: [CMS: 695710K->695710K(3670016K), 16.7364748 secs] 695716K->695710K(4141888K), [CMS Perm : 133237K->133237K(524288K)], 16.7373018 secs] [Times: user=16.77 sys=0.01, real=16.74 secs] 
1242.444: [Full GC1242.444: [CMS: 695710K->695710K(3670016K), 16.4691631 secs] 695727K->695710K(4141888K), [CMS Perm : 133237K->133237K(524288K)], 16.4698573 secs] [Times: user=16.51 sys=0.02, real=16.47 secs] 
1283.740: [GC1283.741: [ParNew: 419456K->33117K(471872K), 0.1520895 secs] 1115166K->728827K(4141888K), 0.1531085 secs] [Times: user=1.06 sys=0.01, real=0.15 secs]
```

Daily i see this in gc.log and , and everytime 2 cycles of no use.

vm parameters are

```
java -server -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseMembar -d64 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:GC.log -classpath ......
```

Available processors (Cores): 16

Edit:
I thought of removing MaxNewSize parameter , as it is 1/8 part of total heap now. And I read in several articles it should be 1/3 to 1/4 of total heap. But i dint get proper explanation how young generation size (MaxNewSize ) will affect GC.

Comment: maybe the program is not doing too much, everything in memory are static stuffs which will not be GCed?

Comment: @Steve In that case why full gc is started , u see application was stuck in that duration.

Comment: Looks like you have a memory leak. Use a profiler like MAT or Yourkit to analyze a memory dump and detect possible leaks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza can u plz explain what makes u feel memory leak , i dont see much of the memory utilized and for that i am going to change few parameters so that we can stop frequent GC.

Comment: After 2 full GC cycles nothing is freed, seems like you're always using all the objects you have created even when you don't need them (thus they should be removed). But this may be only a guess.

Comment: That's looks like impossible.

Comment: Don't forget that if you have finalizers GC needs to run an extra cycle for them.

Comment: @HotLicks can u give any authentic link which tell finalizers need extra cycle in java.

Comment: @Vipin - You can look it up.  The first cycle determines that there's something that would be freed, but can't be because it's finalizer has not run.  The second cycle cleans up the finalized object and any debris it left behind.  And it's possible to have an infinite loop of sorts where the finalizer creates more finalizable objects.

Comment: @HotLicks I got your point , but i have never seen anywhere that finalizers need extra cycle in java. I tried to google it also , can u provide any links which stats same.

Comment: @Vipin - I know it because I worked on an IBM JVM, and the guys on my team who worked on the GC code had access to the Sun code.  (Both our JVM and theirs had to do this -- it's inherent in the spec.)  I have seen reference to it once or twice since, but I can't point at a reference.  You can believe it or not, as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the objects are still active and still have links to them. You may be able to fix this by moving around where you declare and initialize your objects/variables. This is not always possible as it may effect the running of the program. Keep in mind Garbage collection does not always free up space it only frees up space that can be freed up.

Is there a reason you think space should be freed up? Are you manually triggering the Garbage collector or is this simply the automated run of it?

Comment: This log is from my test env , and when I tool around 50 people were working on this application. If there was nothing to freed up why java will start full 3 times?

Comment: There are a few things that can cause the GC to run. First off some one may have manual run it. Did you write all the code in question does it contain any manual runs? GC also stores things in Generations and does some memory compacting so it may be triggering to complete one of these operations. I don't know the intricate specifics of the GC but my guess is there are cases that could cause it to run and not delete anything. Take a look here to see more info on the GC 

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Comment: Even if we have system.gc() calls , we are not forcing jvm. JVM decides after gc call whether to run or not. Here JVM is running 3 cycles out of which 2 are useless. I feel it is my vm parameters which are forcing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the GC logs, few things comes to my mind

1. In this case , the old ten is not full 695 MB out of more than 3 GB. So why does GC triggers?  Few GC cycle runs but does not collects anything from perm or either old gen. Could it due to manual trigger? Remember full GC runs when old gen heap is having fragmentation ( so promotion is difficult ) or InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent is set to too low. Default is 45 for some JVM. You can set this to -XX:+InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70